# Why the favicon links in my index.html file are not working?

Tags: html, favicon

I've seen other links but the truth is my favicon is still not working. Sometimes I do some changes in the code, and the favicon of my portfolio page is only seen once. It stops working once I load the site for the second time.

I went to the site favicon.io and created my own favicon. Like instructed, saved in the root directory of my repository and copy/pasted the code.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">  
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
```

However, those links are not working. Can anyone please advise? Is there any change I need to do?

Comment: are the favicon files in the same directory as your html file?

Comment: Yes. They're both in the root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I submitted my domain to my github.io repository, the links worked. Meaning that basically the favicon can be seen once my site is online with the correct domain.

You can make sure if it will work after ending the site project and publishing it using a domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test favicon without a server add . before /

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./favicon-16x16.png">
```